# Pause application in QML when app is in background Symbian

Tags: background, symbian, qml

I want to know of any pure QML way to find out whether the application is in the background or not and then accordingly stop or play music. In meego the alternate way to do is through the PlatformWindow Element but it does not exist in Symbian QML. Help needed please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it working :) and i did it though Qt way... here are the steps

1) Create a class MyEventFilter

```
class myEventFilter : public QObject
{

bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) {
    switch(event->type()) {
    case QEvent::WindowActivate:
        emit qmlvisiblechange(true);
        qDebug() << "Window activated";

        bis_foreground=true;
        return true;
    case QEvent::WindowDeactivate:
        emit qmlvisiblechange(false);
        qDebug() << "Window deactivated";

        bis_foreground=false;
        return true;
    default:
    return false;
    }
}


 void dosomething();

private:
   int something;
public:
   bool bis_foreground;
      Q_OBJECT
 public slots:
   Q_INVOKABLE QString checkvisibility() {
       if (bis_foreground==true) return "true";
       else return "false";
   }
signals:
    void qmlvisiblechange(bool is_foreground);

};
```

2) Then in main.cpp include this file include the class and add setContext propery like this

```
context->setContextProperty("myqmlobject", &ef);
```

3) in qml file call it like this:

```
 Item {
    id: name
    Connections
    {
        target:myqmlobject
        onQmlvisiblechange:
        {


            if(is_foreground)
            {
              //dont do anything...
            }
            else
            {


                playSound.stop()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a pure QML way?

You can detect if an application has been sent to the background by installing an event filter.
Check: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Detecting_when_a_Qt_application_has_been_switched_to_the_background_and_when_resumed

For a "pure" QML way, there is the `Symbian` QML element:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt-components-symbian/qml-symbian.html

It has a `foreground` property that indicates whether the app is in the foreground or in the background. You can try connecting to `onForegroundChanged`.

From the documentation, the `Symbian` element is not "creatable". It exists as a context property named `symbian`. So a sample usage would be:

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import com.nokia.symbian 1.1

    PageStackWindow {
        id: window
        initialPage: MainPage {tools: toolBarLayout}
        showStatusBar: true
        showToolBar: true

        function appForegroundChanged() {
             console.log("Foreground: " + symbian.foreground)
         }
        function appCurrentTimeChanged() {
             console.log("Current time: " + symbian.currentTime)
         }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            symbian.currentTimeChanged.connect(appCurrentTimeChanged)
            symbian.foregroundChanged.connect(appForegroundChanged)
        }

        ToolBarLayout {


      id: toolBarLayout
        ToolButton {
            flat: true
            iconSource: "toolbar-back"
            onClicked: window.pageStack.depth <= 1 ? Qt.quit() : window.pageStack.pop()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like a pure qml way as I suck at Qt programming...I have looked at the second link you provided.. But somehow my QtCreator does not have the Symbian tag in qml. Could you please try it out in your QtCreator and let me know what I am missing. I have QtSdk 1.1 installed and am using QtQuick 1.1 also. Still the Symbian tag cannot be picked by my ide...