# Audio keeps playing when app is in the background

Tags: qt, qml, qtmultimedia

I have a soundtrack to be played through the run time as the main theme:

```
App{
      ...............
   Audio{
        source: "../assets/Art Of Silence_V2.mp3"
        autoPlay: true
        loops : Audio.Infinite
   }
      .......
}
```

How do I stop it from playing when the app is in the background and resume it afterwards?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's already answered by this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752489/pause-application-in-qml-when-app-is-in-background-symbian

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your application contained in a `Window` or `ApplicationWindow` component

```
Window{
      ...............
   Audio{
        readonly property bool forground : Window.visibility !== Window.Minimized &&
                                             Window.visibility !== Window.Hidden
        source: "../assets/Art Of Silence_V2.mp3"
        autoPlay: true
        loops : Audio.Infinite
        onForgroundChanged: { forground ? start() : stop() }
   }
      .......
}
```

Comment: If you are talking about ```App``` component of Felgo, then it's a ```Window``` subclass and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I was working around the same problem using `Qt.application.state`
whereas

0 - mimimized

2 - lost focus

4 - got focus

```
Audio {
    muted: Qt.application.state === 4
    ...
}
```